# yarn error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I have this json package inside my app, its function is to create icons from an svg to jsx.
It works perfectly on mac, but not on windows.

```
{
    "name": "icons",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "YEMA Icons",
    "private": true,
    "files": [
        "solid/",
        "outline/",
        "README.md"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublishOnly": "yarn build",
        "build": "yarn clean && yarn build-icons-solid && yarn build-icons-outline && node ./scripts/build.js",
        "build-icons-solid": "svgo --config=svgo.solid.yaml -f ./src/solid -o ./optimized/solid --pretty --indent=2 && mkdir -p ./solid && cp -R ./optimized/solid ./solid",
        "build-icons-outline": "svgo --config=svgo.outline.yaml -f ./src/outline -o ./optimized/outline --pretty --indent=2 && mkdir -p ./outline && cp -R ./optimized/outline ./outline",
        "clean": "rimraf ./solid ./outline ./optimized"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.12",
        "@svgr/core": "^5.5.0",
        "camelcase": "^6.0.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "svgo": "^1.3.2"
    }
}
```

output in cmd:

```
icons:build: La sintaxis del comando no es correcta.
icons:build: error Command failed with exit code 1.
icons:build: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
icons:build: error Command failed with exit code 1.
icons:build: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
icons:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (C:\Users\Rafael\Proyectos web\fronts\packages\icons) yarn run build exited (1)
command (C:\Users\Rafael\Proyectos web\fronts\packages\icons) yarn run build exited (1)

 Tasks:    0 successful, 1 total
Cached:    0 cached, 1 total
  Time:    1.869s

 ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I don't know if it is a problem in the syntax of the yarn-build command, between windows and mac, does it exist?